# How to connect to a web server and authenticate a user using groovy?

Tags: groovy, aem, groovy-console

---

Hello Guys,
I am assigned a task to connect to a AEM server using groovy. Also the user id and password is hardcoded inside the script so once the connection is established , the user should be authenticated and proper response should be generated.
I would be glad if anyone could help as I do not know anything about groovy and not much resources are available online!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any sample code that could be a basis for understanding what you are trying to accomplish? Could you post it, or a stripped-down version of it, here?

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to groovy may be you can check few of the posts below which will help you to get a better understanding on groovy.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZoSokB0Qw0w

https://labs.tadigital.com/index.php/2018/12/18/groovy-script-in-aem/

https://medium.com/@ramamity94/update-jcr-on-live-environment-and-much-more-using-aem-groovy-console-c86f032de250